# Display a label depending on a timer with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to display the value of i, rest for 2 sec, then show the new value of i.

But with this code, it just display the very last value of i, not even the original value. Anyone can help me?
Thank you

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep

root=Tk()
touracc=StringVar()
printer=Label(root, textvariable=touracc,bg="#85c17e")
touracc.set('yo')

for i in range(2):
    touracc.set(str(i))
    sleep(2)


printer.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `sleep()` will block tkinter from updating.  Use `after()` instead:

```py
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

touracc=StringVar()
printer=Label(root, textvariable=touracc,bg="#85c17e")
printer.pack()
touracc.set('yo')

def update(n=0):
    if n < 2:    
        touracc.set(n)
        root.after(2000, update, n+1)

root.after(2000, update)
root.mainloop()
```